# Workaround for screen flicker

Tags: c#, wpf

Writing a fairly simple app with c#/wpf.

When opening a second window there is a brief flicker or flash.

Extensive googling says that this caused by screen repainting, so not much I can do about that.

(I haven't included any code because it seems this problem is well known and something most people 'learn to live with')

So, I thought, why not put all the XAML in one file with each page within its own grid that I can hide/show with visibility.visible or visibility.collapsed etc.

Works nicely (apart from a very slight delay - less than 1/2 second - the first time i show the second window grid), but I'm unhappy at the idea of containing all the code behind in a single page. (for what its worth, i'm told that compiler see's it all as one file anyway but ... )

Is there a way I can create separate 'code behind files for each 'windows' (in reality a XAML Grid) functionality whilst linking them all to the same Xaml File?

(I have a horrible feeling having typed this that the answer is obvious and I should already know it ...)

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to create a new Control Class-Code Behind pair for each 'window grid'. This is done in VS by clicking Add-Create Element-User Control (of name `UserControl1.xaml`, rename it to something Like `YourControl.xaml`) in Solution Explorer (I think you already know all this, but just in case).

Now, if there is no *specific* requirement for the control to be of type Grid, you can use it as it is:

```
<MainWindow>
   <Grid>
      <YourControlNumberOne />    
      <YourControlNumberTwo />    
      <YourControlNumberThree />    
   <Grid/>
</MainWindow>
```

If you specifically need `Grid`-based control, just change the base class of `YourControl` to `Grid`, and change the topmost XAML element in the associated XAML file to `Grid`.